# Tableau maps not recognizing worldwide locations

Tags: maps, tableau-api

I'm trying to display my org's client list geographically on tableau maps, but the map isn't able to recognize a lot of cities (1000+ missing)! Has any one faced this problem before, if so can you provide me with some solution?

Thanks

Sagar

Answer (score 1):

The following Knowledge Base articles on mapping basics with Tableau may help to resolve the issue.

- [Mapping Basics](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/mapping-basics)
- [Mapping Data with WMS](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/map-data-wms)

If assistance is still required, then I'd suggest contacting Tableau's support team. It's recommended that support cases are created via the Customer Portal or via the [webform](https://www.tableausoftware.com/support/request). Failing that, just email support@tableausoftware.com (via your registered email address) describing the problem, along with screenshots and a [packaged workbook](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/sending-packaged-workbook).

Comment: I googled up WMS, but I couldn't find any service specific to my use, displaying all the cities in the world correctly.....I've opened a request case via the webform. Thanks for the suggestion!